# Constructor and static functions

Tags: c++, eclipse, optimization, arduino

I have read some of the posts about this problem, but I am not sure about something. When I have a static method and I call it without setting any Object of the class that it belongs like:

The class:

Code:

```
class Fruit {
    static int colour;
    Fruit();
    static int getColour();
    static void setColour();
    virtual ~Fruit();
}
```

The calling the function:

Code:

```
Fruit:getcolour();
```

The implementation of the static function:

```
int Fruit::setColour() {
    return colour;
}
```

Does the constructor get called in order to run the static function?

So if I have the constructor doing something like a initialization of the object (seting the constructor to call setColour() ) will it run before the function `getColour`?

Answer (score 2):

No, the constructor won't get called, nor does it need to get called, because `Fruit::color` **must be defined** in order for this to compile.

So, that's not the full code. The implementation file has something like

```
int Fruit::colour = 42;
```

which is what `getcolour` will return unless you change the value beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming definition of `static` member(*without which your program will fail to compile*) as a detail which you forgot to mention in the OP,

> **Does the constructor get called in order to run the static function?**

No, it doesn't.

`static` methods do not operate on a specific instance of a class so the instance(*and hence call to constructor*) is not needed to call a `static` method.
Also, `static` methods can only operate on `static` class members unless a object instance is explicitly passed to it. Given that `static` members are per class and not per instance, it makes sense that constructor does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a static member function or a static member variable as something a LOT like a global.  If you need a static function to have access to member information, you will need to make a global instance or use one of the singleton patterns (be careful w/ the lazy singleton pattern if you're using it from more than one thread).